# Blazor Hybrid - DVTExtendedPlatformInfo - Problem with debug & build for iOS

Tags: ios, maui-blazor

I have an app that works very well with Android.

the below works for a physical device (ipad) and a simulated device (iphone 14 with iOS 16.2)

When launching (debug) on iOS, the splashscreen appears before facing a blank screen and no interaction possible (Not even the "loading...").
When launching in Release mode on iOS, the app opens and closes almost instantly. No splash screen.

VS Community Version 17.6.2
Xcode 14.3.1

Packages:

- MudBlazor 6.7.0
- Plugin.InAppBilling 7.0.5-beta
- sqlite-net-pcl 1.6.292

## When looking into my logs:

```
2023-08-03 11:52:20.473 mlaunch[10173:157780] Thread Pool Worker DVTAssertions: Warning in /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/Apps/DT/BuildRoots/BuildRoot7/ActiveBuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-21780/DVTFoundation/DeveloperStructure/DVTExtendedPlatformInfo.m:79
Details:  DVTExtendedPlatformInfo: Synthesized watchos Extended Platform Info because no plugin existed to provide it or that plugin was not loaded
Object:   <DVTExtendedPlatformInfo>
Method:   +extendedPlatformInfoForPlatformIdentifier:error:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x600001d7c680>{number = 9, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
```

This specific one appears 4 times every time before the app actually opens to... Blank page.

Using the console from my mac device, I can see the below:

## In Debug:

```
error   11:44:03.707564+0100    kernel  Sandbox: App Name(1681) deny(1) sysctl-read kern.bootargs
error   11:44:03.916393+0100    kernel  Sandbox: App Name(1681) deny(2) file-test-existence /usr/bin/gdb
error   11:44:03.916500+0100    kernel  Sandbox: App Name(1681) deny(2) file-test-existence /bin/gdb
error   11:44:03.916532+0100    kernel  Sandbox: App Name(1681) deny(2) file-test-existence /sbin/gdb
error   11:44:03.916568+0100    kernel  Sandbox: App Name(1681) deny(2) file-test-existence /usr/bin/lldb
error   11:44:03.916771+0100    kernel  Sandbox: App Name(1681) deny(2) file-test-existence /bin/lldb
error   11:44:03.916856+0100    kernel  Sandbox: App Name(1681) deny(2) file-test-existence /sbin/lldb
error   11:44:06.013075+0100    backboardd  ignoring connection; bundleID is missing (or invalid) from the attributes: IOHIDEventSystemConnection uuid:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx pid:1681 process:App Name type:Passive entitlements:0x0 caller:PencilKit: <redacted> + 76 attributes:(null) state:0x0 events:0 mask:0x0 dropped:0 dropStatus:0 droppedMask:0x0 lastDroppedTime:NONE
```

## In Release:

```
error   12:52:39.950027+0100    kernel  1 duplicate report for Sandbox: App Name(1700) deny(1) sysctl-read kern.bootargs
error   12:52:39.950071+0100    kernel  Sandbox: App Name(1712) deny(2) file-test-existence /usr/bin/gdb
error   12:52:39.950115+0100    kernel  Sandbox: App Name(1712) deny(2) file-test-existence /bin/gdb
error   12:52:39.950145+0100    kernel  Sandbox: App Name(1712) deny(2) file-test-existence /sbin/gdb
error   12:52:39.950176+0100    kernel  Sandbox: App Name(1712) deny(2) file-test-existence /usr/bin/lldb
error   12:52:39.950206+0100    kernel  Sandbox: App Name(1712) deny(2) file-test-existence /bin/lldb
error   12:52:39.950246+0100    kernel  Sandbox: App Name(1712) deny(2) file-test-existence /sbin/lldb
error   12:52:40.637070+0100    backboardd  ignoring connection; bundleID is missing (or invalid) from the attributes: IOHIDEventSystemConnection uuid:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx pid:1712 process:App Name type:Passive entitlements:0x0 caller:PencilKit: <redacted> + 76 attributes:(null) state:0x0 events:0 mask:0x0 dropped:0 dropStatus:0 droppedMask:0x0 lastDroppedTime:NONE
error   12:52:40.901303+0100    SpringBoard Advisor: No handle found for currently focused PID: 1712; sceneIdentity: com.apple.frontboard.systemappservices::FBSceneManager:sceneID%3Acom.company.appName-default
error   12:52:40.963718+0100    runningboardd   RBSStateCapture remove item called for untracked item <RBConnectionClient| 1712 name:application<com.company.appName> entitlements:<RBEntitlements| [
            
            ]> inheritanceManager:<RBClientInheritanceManager|  inheritances:[
    <RBSInheritance| environment:UIScene:com.apple.frontboard.systemappservices::FBSceneManager:sceneID%3Acom.company.appName-default name:com.apple.frontboard.visibility origID:30-31-7995 payload>,
    <RBSInheritance| environment:(none) name:com.apple.frontboard.visibility origID:30-31-7987>
    ]>>
error   12:52:41.078602+0100    SpringBoard Scene FBSceneManager/sceneID:com.company.appName-default update failed: <NSError: 0x2801942a0; domain: FBSceneErrorDomain; code: 1 (operation-failed); reason: "Scene update failed."> {
    NSUnderlyingError = <NSError: 0x2801b1c50; domain: FBWorkspace; code: 1; reason: "Scene client is invalid.">;}
error   12:52:41.081595+0100    SpringBoard Ignoring update for invalidated scene: sceneID:ccom.company.appName-default
```

## What I tried:

- Starting a brand new app and copy-pasting everything from the previous one (Expecting there was a problem with the setup, since I did start the setup on a windows for this app). The error persists
- Creating a brand new app from scratch (from the base one MAUI Blazor gives you). Works fine.
- Manually adding an entitlement.plist (with just access to wifi. I do write on the device but couldn't find something about it)

## Current stage:

I'm basically stuck, I don't event understand the error and it seems that googling it doesn't help, I can't find any mention of that framework and how it impacts my code.
My app is just a data/ui app, no API calls, all local using SQLite and a .db file created on the user device.

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem, did you ever find a fix?

Comment: Sadly I couldn't find anything. I've just decided to stop using MAUI as a whole because it's just not ready & I'm tired of having random problems that are due to the framework and not my own mistakes.

Comment: @CrashM did you get anywhere with this? I'm experiencing the same issue with my iOS release build crashing on start. The iOS Debug build works fine, as do both Android builds.